# Stop DHCP services on Linux - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ethernet, dhcp

How do I stop DHCP services on a particular ethernet port in Linux ? I was trying to take full control of an ethernet port of my computer to inject packets into the device plugged into it without being interfered by DHCP request traffic.

Comment: Is your intention to disable DHCP and configure a static IP address on an eth interface? [Ubuntu Network Configuration Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic#Configuring_an_interface)

Answer (score 2):

As far as an interface getting an IP via DHCP, that's controlled by `/etc/network/interfaces` - change any `dhcp` you find in the appropriate stanzas to `static`.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621261/masquerading-a-webserver
I want to setup a connection with my network device and respond to the GET request it is sending with my local webserver Perl script. I thought I should disable all system service before I can inject http traffic into the port.

Comment: Probably want to disable NetworkManager if it's running, `service stop NetworkManager` or similar.  Then you may want to run `lsof -i` or `netstat` to see what else is listening, and stop programs or disable services accordingly if you want absolutely no other traffic on that interface.